# Working with Facebook like API and opengraph

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-opengraph

The Documentation from facebook isn't understandable, atleast for me.

I have never worked before with facebook and had a basic requirement of putting a like button on Product pages.

So yesterday, I added the OpenGraph meta tags and like button to my Product pages as stated in this documentation, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/. I also created an app, as the document stated that it has extended the basic meta data to add a required field to connect your webpage with Facebook: **fb:app_id**.

The like button has been set but i have few queries which are as following :-

1. For some pages, the like button doesn't read the og tags. Rather than publishing the whole thing in a story manner by reading og tags, it just shows a link. During googling, I read it happens because of facebook caching and since, I shared the link on facebook before putting the meta-tags, this is happening. So, Is there any way that I can direct facebook to reset all the caching for my pages or scraping that it has done earlier.
2. Though I have created the App, I actually have no idea what to do with it. Why is it needed and what matters it can help me with.
3. I tested one of my URLs here: [Facebook Linter](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) but it shows some error and stuff which i can't understand. Below is the image. Please tell if I have done anything wrong and why it's showing these errors

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Documentation for OpenGraph on Facebook containing outdated information about pre-defined types, see [OpenGraph Types](http://ogp.me/#types). You probably need to define your custom Object Type "Product" in for your Application/Site using Developer Application in Open Graph settings.

You may want to read Documentation for [OpenGraph beta](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/beta/) too.

**Update:**
There is a similar question about exactly this `og:type`: [Opengraph meta tag og:type set to “product” errors (like button & URL linter/debug)](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/8479503/opengraph-meta-tag-ogtype-set-to-product-errors-like-button-url-linter-deb)

Comment: I tried checking the well-known product sites on Facebook URL debug tool to see the type they use. And I found that they are sticking to the same type: "product". There pages too shows the same error results like mine. May be since product is so natural type, people expect it to be added.....I am too thinking of sticking to the same type, is it right way to go ??

Comment: This type worked at some point of type (as stated on [outdated documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/)), but stopped to work. It's removed, so probably it's not going to back (just speculating on this). You can add this type under your application namespace.

Comment: I am not sure how to do that....This [LINK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/beta/opengraph/simpletypes/) provides the information but i am not sure how to achieve this task...

Comment: @PankajUpadhyay read the [Step by step tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/beta/opengraph/tutorial/) provided by Facebook.